# iOS Metal - reusing code by using helper methods

Tags: ios, ios9, metal

I am trying to reuse code between a few shaders, each written in its own metal file. I moved the duplicate code to a helper method in a new metal file and trying to call this method from the existing shaders.

The project compiles and run but it seems that the helper method is not being called as expected.

Is it possible to reuse code in such way?